# Cannot set true value for I18nManager.allowRTL

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, i18next

I would like to enable RTL on my iOS project using EXPO.

Then I tried to enable like

```
I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
```

It cannot be set to true.I checked the value by using the following code

`console.log('Value is: '+I18nManager.isRTL);`//This always retuns FALSE

Please help me how to solve this issue

Comment: are u solve it?